# How subclass master AND another class used by master in Python

Tags: python

I have subclassed a large master class from a library. My subclass works fine but I now want to also subclass another class used by the master. But, I don't see how without editing the master class to use my new subclass.  Put another way, I want to signal that usage of class "abc' in subclass of master should be replaced by a subclass of 'abc' Here is some pseudocode to illustrate the problem where I want to inherit getenginestats but using a subclassed return type. I know I can override a method or two but the second class is used all over the master so that is not a practical approach.

```
class vehicle(object):
    horsepower = 0

    def getenginestats():
        # returns an enginestats object
        stats = EngineStats()
        stats.rpm = 1000
        return stats



class EngineStats(object):
    rpm = 0

class MyEngineStats(EngineStats):
    # add battery voltage to stats
    voltage = 0

class ElectricCar(vehicle)
    batterysize = 0



prius = ElectricCar()
# how do I get ElectricCar.getenginestats into a MyEngineStats object??
mystats = prius.getenginestats
myvoltage  = mystats.voltage
```

Bill

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function `getenginestats()` and fix some typos:

```
class vehicle(object):
    horsepower = 0

    def getenginestats(self):
        # returns an enginestats object
        stats = MyEngineStats()
        stats.rpm = 1000
        return stats

class EngineStats(object):
    rpm = 0

class MyEngineStats(EngineStats):
    # add battery voltage to stats
    voltage = 1500

class ElectricCar(vehicle):
    batterysize = 0



prius = ElectricCar()
mystats = prius.getenginestats()
myvoltage  = mystats.voltage
print(myvoltage)
```

returns:

```
1500
```

---

You would need to overwrite the randint function (for example):

```
import random

def _randint(a, b):
    return MyInt(random.original_randint(a, b))


class MyInt(int):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyInt, cls).__new__(cls, args[0])

    def isOdd(self):
        return 

_min = MyInt(0)
_max = MyInt(9)

random.original_randint = random.randint
random.randint = _randint

x = random.randint(_min, _max)
print(type(x), x)
```

Returns:

```
(<class '__main__.MyInt'>, 3)
```

Comment: Let me try a simpler but stupid example:  Pretend  I am a fan of odd numbers and want to add an .isodd propery to integer int. I can subsclass int as myint to do this - easy. But how do I subclass some other class  that uses int - eg random AND have the subclass use myint throughout INSTEAD of int?

Comment: @Bill: There's no general way to change the types another class uses. It depends entirely on how the class is implemented. Maybe you can pass it in a class to use somewhere, but maybe not. `random.randint` is always going to return an `int`, not some other subclass of `int`. If you want your custom random subclass to do it differently, you'll probably need to override all of its methods.

Comment: Apologies _ I am having trouble explaining my issue clearly.  My point with Random is that IF I wanted to subclass Random  how would I do it so it also uses myint without overloading every function that uses int?  Is there something like super.replace classdef1 with classdef2 to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback. Sounds like it is not possible to do this "nested subclassing"? 
I think this would be useful to others too given that many libraries have helper classes for structures and enums. If I can subclass somebiglibrary, why not allow me to also subclass the somebiglibrarystatus(enum) into my subclass.

Easy to work around but would have been nice.

Thanks

Bill